# UITabBar change view hierarchy after rotating process. (or changes its position in view hierarchy)

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, uiview-hierarchy, nslayoutanchor

I have a view with several subviews (with only one peculiarity I added tabBar as a subview to a view of VC)

```
   super.viewDidLoad()
   view.addSubview((tabBarController?.tabBar)!)
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    view.addSubview(pageControl)

    view.addSubview(skipButton)
    view.addSubview(nextButton)
    print( view.constraints)

    nextButton.anchorWithConstantsToTop(view.topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right:
    view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 16, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0)
    nextButtonTopAnchor = nextButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0)
    nextButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    nextButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    skipButton.anchorWithConstantsToTop(view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 16, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0)
    skipButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    skipButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true


     pageControl.anchorWithConstantsToTop(nil, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: tabBarController?.tabBar.topAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 28, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 30)
    pageControl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 121).isActive = true



    collectionView.anchorToTop(view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor)
```

Something bizarre (for me) happend when I rotate device. 
1) in portrait orientation everything ok. All subviews stands in hierarchy chain as they are supposed to. (especially UITabBar)[image]
but then after rotation process to landscape orientation UITabbar separates from UIView, and of course constraint regarding to pageControl bottom: tabBarController?.tabBar.topAnchor is vanished. 
[image]
Why is it happens?

Comment: This looks like an odd approach... Why not use the built-in TabBar? Are you setting constraints on the `tabBar` you're manually adding to the view?